# Device limits for FCM Topic messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

It is written in the docs that "***FCM topic messaging allows you to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic.***"

My question is -

- Is there a limit on the **number of devices** (per send/request) in this case?

And for the statement - ***"For fast, secure delivery to single devices or small groups of devices"***.

- Can you give me an approximate number of this 'small group'?

[Topic messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging)

Comment: 1. No there is no limit. Any number to devices will receive the FCM topic message which are subscribed for the topic.

2. Small group corresponds to the device a single user has. Like if a user has 3 phones, you can send FCM to all three devices at once. I don't think, somebody (a person) would have more than 1000 devices all running at the same time.

Comment: about the PS, the info I gave you is in the docs.  I'd recommend you to please re-read it.

Comment: For a large group of users (say 5000) subscribed to a topic 'blah' - When I trigger the post request, would these 5000 receive the notification? Your current answer suggests that all 5000 would receive it (or maybe I'm missing something). The current docs only point to the 1000/request limit for sending notifications through registration tokens. Note that I'm talking about a single send/post request here. @RahulKumar

Comment: Yes. It does. I use it to send notification to over million devices.

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me @RahulKumar :-)